# Java: client server reverse functionality of classes

Tags: java, sockets, client-server, audio-streaming

Maybe this is a little off-topic but i really need help. im stuck for days.
Im making a real time audio stream programm with sockets in java.
The following code parts are client and server. The client sends audio stream to server,and the stream is playing to my server speakers.
I need to do the opposite. Stream audio from server to client's speakers. How to reverse those code parts so to achieve that? im really confused

client

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class VUClient extends JFrame {

boolean stopaudioCapture = false;
ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream;
AudioFormat adFormat;
TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
AudioInputStream InputStream;
SourceDataLine sourceLine;
Graphics g;

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new VUClient();
}

public VUClient() {
    final JButton capture = new JButton("Capture");
    final JButton stop = new JButton("Stop");
    final JButton play = new JButton("Playback");

    capture.setEnabled(true);
    stop.setEnabled(false);
    play.setEnabled(false);

    capture.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            capture.setEnabled(false);
            stop.setEnabled(true);
            play.setEnabled(false);
            captureAudio();
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(capture);

    stop.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            capture.setEnabled(true);
            stop.setEnabled(false);
            play.setEnabled(true);
            stopaudioCapture = true;
            targetDataLine.close();
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(stop);

    play.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            playAudio();
        }
    });
    getContentPane().add(play);

    getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setTitle("Capture/Playback Demo");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(400, 100);
    getContentPane().setBackground(Color.white);
    setVisible(true);

    g = (Graphics) this.getGraphics();
}

private void captureAudio() {
    try {
        adFormat = getAudioFormat();
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, adFormat);
        targetDataLine = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        targetDataLine.open(adFormat);
        targetDataLine.start();

        Thread captureThread = new Thread(new CaptureThread());
        captureThread.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StackTraceElement stackEle[] = e.getStackTrace();
        for (StackTraceElement val : stackEle) {
            System.out.println(val);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private void playAudio() {
    try {
        byte audioData[] = byteOutputStream.toByteArray();
        InputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
        AudioFormat adFormat = getAudioFormat();
        InputStream = new AudioInputStream(byteInputStream, adFormat, audioData.length / adFormat.getFrameSize());
        DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, adFormat);
        sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
        sourceLine.open(adFormat);
        sourceLine.start();
        Thread playThread = new Thread(new PlayThread());
        playThread.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        System.exit(0);
    }
}

private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 16000.0F;
    int sampleInbits = 16;
    int channels = 1;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = false;
    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleInbits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
}

class CaptureThread extends Thread {

    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

    public void run() {

        byteOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        stopaudioCapture = false;
        try {
            DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket(8786);
            InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
            while (!stopaudioCapture) {
                int cnt = targetDataLine.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length);
                if (cnt > 0) {
                    DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(tempBuffer, tempBuffer.length, IPAddress, 9786);
                    clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
                    byteOutputStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
                }
            }
            byteOutputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("CaptureThread::run()" + e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

class PlayThread extends Thread {

    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

    public void run() {
        try {
            int cnt;
            while ((cnt = InputStream.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length)) != -1) {
                if (cnt > 0) {
                   sourceLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
                }
            }
            //                sourceLine.drain();
            //             sourceLine.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;

public class VUServer {

ByteArrayOutputStream byteOutputStream;
AudioFormat adFormat;
TargetDataLine targetDataLine;
AudioInputStream InputStream;
SourceDataLine sourceLine;

private AudioFormat getAudioFormat() {
    float sampleRate = 16000.0F;
    int sampleInbits = 16;
    int channels = 1;
    boolean signed = true;
    boolean bigEndian = false;
    return new AudioFormat(sampleRate, sampleInbits, channels, signed, bigEndian);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    new VUServer().runVOIP();
}

public void runVOIP() {
    try {
        DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9786);
        byte[] receiveData = new byte[10000];
        while (true) {
            DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
            serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
            System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + receivePacket.getAddress().getHostAddress() + " " + receivePacket.getPort());
            try {
                byte audioData[] = receivePacket.getData();
                InputStream byteInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
                AudioFormat adFormat = getAudioFormat();
                InputStream = new AudioInputStream(byteInputStream, adFormat, audioData.length / adFormat.getFrameSize());
                DataLine.Info dataLineInfo = new DataLine.Info(SourceDataLine.class, adFormat);
                sourceLine = (SourceDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(dataLineInfo);
                sourceLine.open(adFormat);
                sourceLine.start();
                Thread playThread = new Thread(new PlayThread());
                playThread.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class PlayThread extends Thread {

    byte tempBuffer[] = new byte[10000];

    public void run() {
        try {
            int cnt;
            while ((cnt = InputStream.read(tempBuffer, 0, tempBuffer.length)) != -1) {
                if (cnt > 0) {
                    sourceLine.write(tempBuffer, 0, cnt);
                }
            }
            //  sourceLine.drain();
            // sourceLine.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
}
```